# Не меняет баланс при заходе на страницу

Tags: phpmyadmin

захожу как пользователь, перехожу на главную страницу и должно изменить баланс но не изменяет заходил в phpmyadmin баланс не поменялся.

скажите в чем проблема.
вот код

```
<? phprequire "db.php"; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php if( isset($_SESSION['logged_user']) ) : ?>
 Авторизован<br>
  Привет, 


 <?php
 echo $_SESSION['logged_user']->login.'<br>';
 echo $_SESSION['logged_user']->balans.'<br>';

 $sql = "update users set balans = (20) WHERE login = (login)";
 echo "yes";
 ?>!

<from action="index.php" method="POST">
<hr>
<p>
 <button type="submit" name="ind">+++++</button>
</p>
<a href="/logout.php">Выйти</a>
</from>
</body> 
</html>

<?php else : ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

    ?>
 <a href="/login.php">Авторизоваться</a><br>
 <a href="/signup.php">Регистрация</a>
</body>
</html>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Думаете вы создали переменную с именем **$sql** и она должна автоматически исполнится как sql запрос?

Comment: А где код выполнения sql?